# How to get a image in my border right

Tags: css, border

I have a border right applied to this div. It currently runs a line down the page, I want to keep that line but also implement an image to appear in that border right line half way down the page, here is my current css:

```
.aboutMenuArticle {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  left: -27%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

Here is an image of how I need it to look:

[image]

Does anyone know how I could achieve this? Many thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Could you show us what this is supposed to look like?

Comment: the word info is the image which I want to place in the border right half way down the page, splitting the border line

Comment: Could you make a JSfiddle of what you have so far? Frankly, In this case, I'd be using the `border-image` property but it's a little complex and does require an actual image.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a quick fiddle where you absolutely position an after so it's sitting right in the middle. The negative value of right should be half the width of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/n28r5/

```
div {
background: #CCC;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
padding: 20px;
background-clip:content-box;
position: relative;
}

div:after {
    width: 20px;
    height: 48px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(http://red-rockfinancial.com/images/info.jpg);
}
```

Comment: just hosted the url of the background on my site for convenience.